# Coral Dev Board - eth0 MAC address always randomized

Tags: google-coral, mendel-os

I have a Google Coral Dev Board acquired 4/19 and activated 4/22.  When "Mendel GNU/Linux 5 (Eagle)" commences, I am able to successfully connect via wifi because the MAC address is permanent and I have provisioned an assigned IP for that MAC address.  However, with the LAN eth0, there is something that is causing the eth0 to be assigned a random MAC address.  I realize I can go back and configure eth0 to a fixed IP or possibly assign is a fixed MAC address, but it seems to me the LAN port ought to have a consistent MAC address, or if it is intended that random MAC addresses be assigned to the LAN port, there be documented a way to opt out of such a setting and just have the LAN have a consistent/permanent MAC address.  My understanding is that manufacturers of LAN components have pre-assigned pools of MAC addresses that they can assign to each and every LAN product they sell so each has a unique MAC address.  Maybe that practice does not apply to development boards?

From my `dmesg -T`

```
[Fri May 20 05:33:01 2022] fec 30be0000.ethernet eth0: registered PHC device 0
[Fri May 20 05:33:01 2022] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 3.2.6-k
[Fri May 20 05:33:01 2022] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2015 Intel Corporation.
[Fri May 20 05:33:01 2022] igb: Intel(R) Gigabit Ethernet Network Driver - version 5.4.0-k
[Fri May 20 05:33:01 2022] igb: Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Intel Corporation.
[Fri May 20 05:33:01 2022] igbvf: Intel(R) Gigabit Virtual Function Network Driver - version 2.4.0-k
[Fri May 20 05:33:01 2022] igbvf: Copyright (c) 2009 - 2012 Intel Corporation.


[Fri May 20 05:33:01 2022] libphy: Fixed MDIO Bus: probed
[Fri May 20 05:33:01 2022] NXP PHY: loading NXP PHY driver: [autonomous mode]
[Fri May 20 05:33:01 2022] tun: Universal TUN/TAP device driver, 1.6
[Fri May 20 05:33:01 2022] CAN device driver interface
[Fri May 20 05:33:01 2022] fec 30be0000.ethernet: 30be0000.ethernet supply phy not found, using dummy regulator
[Fri May 20 05:33:01 2022] pps pps0: new PPS source ptp0
[Fri May 20 05:33:01 2022] fec 30be0000.ethernet (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): Invalid MAC address: 00:00:00:00:00:00
[Fri May 20 05:33:01 2022] fec 30be0000.ethernet (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): Using random MAC address: 86:45:fd:f5:4a:37
```

What settings do I need to configure to prevent the random MAC address assignment?

Comment: Well yes, devel boards may not have unique addresses. The only purpose of randomization is IMHO to prevent collisions when using multiple boards in same lan.
I guess someone will provide more straight forward answer but in general permanent mac can be set into linux device tree or in u-boot variable (if it uses u-boot) 
Or simply override it using if up script.

Comment: Can you try to run this command and see if its fix the isssue: sudo /etc/runonce.d/10-set-mac-addresses https://github.com/google-coral/edgetpu/issues/558#issuecomment-1077690675

Comment: As requested by @Coral-So-Support, but first:

   `mendel@coral1:~$ cat /sys/class/net/eth0/address
    86:45:fd:f5:4a:37
    mendel@coral1:~$ `

and as requested:    

    `mendel@coral1:~$ sudo /etc/runonce.d/10-set-mac-addresses
    Wifi/Bt MAC address will be 86:45:fd:f5:4a:38
    mendel@coral1:~$`

**now my wifi will be off** as my router will not recognize 86:45:fd:f5:4a:38.  I'll have to reboot.